Selecting sheets based off of a dynamic range, then exporting
I have an export button in my excel workbook that selects sheets to export to as a joined PDF. I originally had the sheets hard coded. For example: Sheets(Array("Volume Report","Notes","Invoice01")).Select and that worked. I tried to get fancy with it by dynamically building the list from a named range that populates with new sheets as I add them to the workbook.
I am able to build the string and it returns the string value that if manually replaced works but when passed as a variable I get Runtime Error '9': Subscript out of Range Im not sure why manually passing the string works but dynamically assigning it does not. Any help in accomplishing the intended task is appreciated.
The VBA code:
Sub ExportAsPDF()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
Dim filePath As String
Dim sheetNames As String
Dim cell As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet

' Build the file path
filePath = wb.Path & "\" & "0_" & Range("Notes_Revision").Value & ") " & Range("Notes_JobName").Value & " - VR - " & Range("Notes_Author").Value & ".pdf"

' Manually build a string of sheet names from Ref_PrintRange
For Each cell In Range("Ref_PrintRange")
    If sheetNames = "" Then
        sheetNames = cell.Value
    Else
        sheetNames = sheetNames & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & cell.Value
    End If
Next cell

' Select the specified sheets for export
Sheets(Array(sheetNames)).Select

' Export the selected sheets as PDF
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=filePath, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False

' Reselect the original sheet
currentSheet.Select

End Sub

Thank you in advance.

Transposing Ref_PrintRange will make it a 1D array that can be used to select a range of worksheets.
[] can be used as a shorthand for Evaluate. Here I use Transpose(Ref_PrintRange)] to convert the values.
Sub ExportAsPDF()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim filePath As String
   
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet

    ' Build the file path
    filePath = wb.Path & "\" & "0_" & Range("Notes_Revision").Value & ") " & Range("Notes_JobName").Value & " - VR - " & Range("Notes_Author").Value & ".pdf"

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets([Transpose(Ref_PrintRange)]).Select
    
    ' Export the selected sheets as PDF
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=filePath, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    ' Reselect the original sheet
    currentSheet.Select

End Sub

Addendum
BigBen pointed that I'm assuming that Ref_PrintRange is a column.  So for completeness:
If Ref_PrintRange is a column use:

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets([Transpose(Ref_PrintRange)]).Select


If Ref_PrintRange is a row use:

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets([Transpose(Transpose(Ref_PrintRange))]).Select


Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 can use TOCOL for row or column data:

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets([Transpose(TOCOL(Ref_PrintRange))]).Select



@BigBen, Transpose a column value once converts it to a 1D array.  Transposing a row converts it to a column.  We'd have to transpose the row twice: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets([Transpose(Transpose(Ref_PrintRange))]).Select

I updated my answer @BigBen.  I misread your initial comment. y attention is usually split when I'm on SO.

Oh this is elegant and simple! Couldn't get is to work at first until I realized it was trying to select hidden sheets. Once I excluded that this just worked.

I'm glad that I could help. Thanks for accepting my anwer @Bryce

Without building an array:
...
Dim first As Boolean
...
first = True
For Each cell In currentSheet.Range("Ref_PrintRange")
    wb.WorkSheets(cell.Value).Select First
    first = False 'Next Select's will add to the current sheet 
                  '   selection instead of replacing it
Next cell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.select

Export Sheets Listed in a Range to PDF Using an Array

When you pass the comma/space delimited sheet names to the Array function, it results in an array with a single element containing the string. This cannot work.
The following covers some of the surprises you may encounter when using such a simplistic approach.

Sub ExportAsPDF()
    
    ' Reference the workbook and the original worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' If it's the workbook containing this code, use 'ThisWorkbook' instead.
    Dim ows As Worksheet: Set ows = wb.ActiveSheet
    ' If you know its name, then use it, e.g. 'Set ows = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")'.
    
    ' Build the file path
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = wb.Path & "\" & "0_" _
        & ows.Range("Notes_Revision").Value & ") " _
        & ows.Range("Notes_JobName").Value & " - VR - " _
        & ows.Range("Notes_Author").Value & ".pdf"
    
    ' Declare additional variables
    Dim sh As Object, cell As Range, CellValue As Variant
    Dim SheetNames() As String, SheetName As String, SheetsCount As Long
    ' Note that 'Dim sh As Object' includes printing charts.
     
    ' Build a String array of sheet names from range 'Ref_PrintRange'
    For Each cell In ows.Range("Ref_PrintRange").Cells
        CellValue = cell.Value
        If Not IsError(CellValue) Then ' no error
            If Len(CellValue) > 0 Then ' no blank
                SheetName = CStr(CellValue)
                ' Attempt to reference the sheet
                Set sh = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                    Set sh = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
                On Error GoTo 0
                ' If successful, add it to the array.
                If Not sh Is Nothing Then ' sheet exists
                    SheetsCount = SheetsCount + 1
                    ReDim Preserve SheetNames(1 To SheetsCount)
                    SheetNames(SheetsCount) = SheetName
                '-Else ' sheet doesn't exist; do nothing
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Exit if no sheets
    If SheetsCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No sheets found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Select the specified sheets for export
    wb.Sheets(SheetNames).Select
    
    ' Export the selected sheets as PDF
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FilePath, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    
    ' Reselect the original sheet
    ows.Select
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Exported " & SheetsCount & " sheet" _
        & IIf(SheetsCount = 1, "", "s") & " to PDF:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Join(SheetNames, vbLf), vbInformation

End Sub

